# Get closest "link_id" to coordinate

Tags: here-api, here-fleet-telematics

I already contacted Here about this but they suggested I asked here.
**Does someone have a way to get the closest "link_id" to a coordinate through Here API?**

Comment: It may be helpful if you can add the exact HERE APIs you are using or want to use. There are many different APIs and endpoints available.

Comment: @Datasun Hi, that's my exact question, I cannot find an API that returns what I want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the link ID Data from the Fleet Telematics - Advanced Dataset API

https://developer.here.com/documentation/advanced-datasets-api/dev_guide/topics/examples.html

You can follow this example below to get an idea.
https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/pde_street_details